# Eliminate words with special characters in a string

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I am trying to select string (Part No-Quantity) which has structure digits{3-5} space digits{1-4}

```
e.g. 1234 20 or 1234 20.00
```

Problem is my RegEx is capturing string format like 1234 12.54 or 1234 12.
I cannot select 1234 12 as it is substring of 1234 12.54. If the main string was 1234 12.00, I would have selected it.

Here are the RegEx I have tried

```
(\d\d\d\d?\d?)(\s+|\t)(\d{1,4})

(\d\d\d\d?\d?)(\s+|\t)(\d{1,4}(?!.[1-9])

(\d\d\d\d?\d?)(\s+|\t)(\d{1,4}(?=\.00)?
```

Expected results is to select 1234 20 or 1234 20.00

Not to select any string like 1234 12.54 or even 1234 12 (substring of 1234 12.54)

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: I am implementing UiPath,, which I believe uses .Net

Answer (score 0):

You could match 3-5 digits and use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match either 1-2 digits followed by a dot and 1-2 times a zero or match 1-4 digits.

At the end use a negative lookahead to assert what is on the right is not a non whitespace char.

**Note** that `\s` also matches `\t` and also a newline.

```
\b\d{3,5}\s+(?:\d{1,2}\.0{1,2}|\d{1,4})(?!\S)
```

In parts

- `\b` Word boundary
- `\d{3,5}\s+` Match 3, 4 or 5 digits followed by 1+ whitespace chars
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\d{1,2}\.0{1,2}` Match 1 or 2 digits, a dot and 1 or 2 times a zero
  - `|` Or
  - `\d{1,4}` Match 1, 2, 3 or 4 digits
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `(?!\S)` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is not a non whitespace car

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7LAiGs/1)

Comment: Thanks for the response,the code \d{1,4} will select 1234 12 (the substring of 1234 12.54) after the alternation.

Comment: It does not match `1234 12` in `1234 12.54` You can check the demo link.

Comment: @SushilDarveshi Can you give some more examples about what should and should not be matched?